# Mouseenter and Mousemove is not triggered in Desktop (touch display ) in Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, dom-events

I have run the tooltip sample using Ionic Framework in Google Chrome.

In Desktop Mode,
when hover the element, the tooltip is shown But when I tap (touch display) that element, the tooltip is not triggered.
In tooltip source, I have bound  the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event for the non-touched device.

In Responsive mode,
when tap/hover the target element, the tooltip is shown.
In tooltip source, I have bound the tap and `mouseleave` event for touch device.

My Question is, When I tap to focus the target element in desktop (touch display), why `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find these mouse events documented in ionic docs.  However, gestures are documented here http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures
You might be able to use (tap) and which does work.